# php / mysql application to work offline when network is lost

Tags: php, mysql, offlineapps

I have a php/mysql application which i want to make it running even if the network connection is lost. so that the data can be synced later once the network is back. What would be the best architecture for implementing such an application ?

Comment: Since both php and mysql sits on the server side, there is no way to make such application to work off line. You have to have something deployed on the client side with some local storage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. But is local storage meant for sites with high volumes of data??

Comment: If you want off line operation, then forget the concept of sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host the application locally and access it through your browser as `localhost/myapp`

Take a look at [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). It should set you up with the things you need to host locally.

Once you come online, you can run a script that will diff your local mySQL database with your remote and sync changes.

Let me know if you need any other info, or if something wasn't clear.